# How to pass a ref to a child component that is wrapped in a higher-order component - TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components, use-ref

I am having a bit of trouble with the useRef hook with TypeScript and within a higher-order-component and was wandering if anyone would have a better insight into where I'm going wrong.

I am trying to pass the ref down from a parent component to the child via the ref prop. However, the child component is 'wrapped' in a higher-order component and I'm unsure how to resolve this.

I have tried implicitly adding types to the useRef hook, but to no avail. I am able to get it to work without the higher-order component, but I'm struggling to pass the ref to the child.

**I am getting the following error:**

```
Type '{ ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322
```

Here are my components:

**Parent Component**

```
const App = () => {

  function handleNavClick() {
    window.scrollTo(0, aboutRef.current!.offsetTop);
  }

  const aboutRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header onNavClick={handleNavClick} />
      <Main>
        <Home />
        <About ref={aboutRef} />
        <Contact />
      </Main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Child Component**

```
import SectionWrapper from "../../wrappers/section/SectionWrapper";
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";

const About = (props: any, ref: any) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="s__about" style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionWrapper(forwardRef(About));
```

**Higher-order component**

```
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

export default (Component: React.FC): React.FC => {
  return function WrappedComponent(props: any): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Container>
      </section>
    );
  };
};
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Quick reply here, have a look at 'forwarding refs' - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html